# If I changed mapreduce's configuration, should I restart the yarn

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

For example, I have a MapReduce job running in my system. And I change the `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` configuration in `mapred-site.xml`.  Will the running parameter of this task change dynamically? Or `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` parameter will take effect in the next run? Or I have to restart the system to make parameter take effect.

Recently, I want to develop an automatic parameter adjustment system for Hadoop, which can dynamically change the parameters according to the load of the system during the running of the task. But I don't know how to develop it. If Hadoop provides relevant API officially, I hope someone can give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your configuration is cluster specific, you have to restart whole cluster, on the other hand if job specific, restart your job to take effect. Some properties are cluster specific actually.The `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` property can be both of them.

No way to change properties while the job is running. Restart your job to take effect.

Comment: If I change the job-specific parameter, will it take effect for the next new job?

Comment: As I said, It will take effect on the next run.